# Change User Agent

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control, watin, user-agent

I am using Watin and i want to change User Agent can it be done in watin c#.Some websites say it is done by changing registries and some say that IE8 has addon to change that but i want to change it by programming

Comment: what do you mean by User Agent of IE?

Comment: that was a mistake.I just want to change user agent

Comment: @Afnan Can you not edit the Windows registry from C#? See [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry).

Comment: ok now how to modify registry to change User agent

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser control? What is your scenario? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: no I am not using web browser but using watin that launches IE

Comment: this thread was something different Please see this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575430/user-agent-switcher-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last comment I am not sure if you are familiar with registry classes. Here are some  tutorials on accessing and modifying registry.

- [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx)
- [Dream in code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/40008-working-with-windows-registry-in-c%23/#/)
- [C-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithWindowsRegistry11282005045112AM/WorkingwithWindowsRegistry.aspx)

Then you need to modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\User Agent key.

You can find detailed explanation about user agent string at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503.aspx?id=uaregistry#UnderstandUA).

You can test your user agent string at [useragentstrings](http://useragentstring.com/index.php)

You can find list of user agent string [here](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Here's a small guide on changing user agent string at [pctools](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/799/).

Comment: lets say if i place user agent for mozila there at register then every page i visit via IE will be as if i am visiting by firefox?

Comment: @Afnan Well that's what the document says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503.aspx?id=uaregistry#ViewingUA

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Internet Explorer
---------------------------
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)

Comment: i have installed chrome firefox and IE on my system then why user agent is mozila :)

Comment: @Afnan I am sorry, what do you mean by that? Do you want to change it to something else?

Comment: in other word i want to make something like this but make it in c# and then launch IE http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18450/change-the-user-agent-string-in-internet-explorer-8/

Answer (score 0):

If You will decide not to do it by progamming, Firefox has an addon called "User Agent Switcher" which works great.
Maybe It will help You.

Comment: Please use comments for a suggestion.

Comment: If I could add acomment, I would, But I need to get to 50 in order to do so.