# USER AGENT Switcher Design

Tags: c#, user-agent

I am using Watin I want to select different USER Agent before launching IE so that it emulates and behaves like user string entered or selected.or in other words i like to implement same as http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18450/change-the-user-agent-string-in-internet-explorer-8/
but in c# not in IE

Comment: I have edited my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575073/change-user-agent/4575307#4575307 Are you still facing any problems?

Comment: Yes I changed User agent as said in link but it did not showed up when i run http://useragentstring.com/index.php it remains same

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer? You will have to modify the default key, and add  Compatible, Version, Platform keys using registry class. First try editing the keys manually, and if still there's a problem let me know what steps you have taken.